# Creating a one-to-one mapping between a N-length list and M workers?

Tags: algorithms

I have a list of length *N*, and I have *M* workers.  I want each of my workers to independently select a contiguous section of the list, with the property that every element of my list is selected by exactly one worker.

Using the SQL notion of `offset` and `limit`, I have an approximation:

`offset = (worker_number / total_workers * list_length).to_i
limit = list_length / total_workers + 1`

The problem is that, for some values of `N` and `M`, this results in overlaps, where some elements are processed multiple times.

Is there a general solution that ensures the one-to-one correspondence between elements and workers, yet allows each worker to independently compute their `offset` and `limit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Give the $i$th worker the range of items at indices from $\lfloor Ni/M \rfloor$ to $\lfloor N(i+1)/M \rfloor - 1$.

Here I assume indices range from $0$ to $N-1$, and workers are indexed by $i$, where $i$ ranges from $0$ to $M-1$.  Also, the notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ represents the result of rounding $x$ down to the nearest integer.

This ensures that there are no overlaps, and the list is split evenly among the workers (as evenly as possible: each worker receives either $\lfloor N/M \rfloor$ items or $\lfloor N/M \rfloor + 1$ items).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  This appears to work for the case of N=4, M=5, but is there a proof that it works for all N and M > 0?

Comment: Also, you have a typo: you're using ceiling notation when defining floor.

Comment: Oh, also -- is there a name or a source for this algorithm?

Comment: Thanks, @Philip.  I've fixed the typo.  There's a proof but it's not very illuminating -- instead, I suggest trying a few examples if you want to see how it works.  There's no name for this that I know of: it's just basic arithmetic and rounding, nothing special.